# ASP MVC 3 bind model of different class type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, binding, controller

Assuming I have two classes (Product & ProductSearch) with the same Property "Title"

If I have a field in my form:

```
<input type="textbox" name="Product.Title" id="Product_Title"/>
```

I can bind it in the controller using:

```
public ActionResult Search(Product product)
```

But is there any way I can specify a bind argument so that it binds to:

```
public ActionResult Search(ProductSearch productSearch)
```

I tried `[Bind(Prefix = "Product")]` to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

The `[Bind(Prefix = "Product")]` should work. Example:

Model:

```
public class ProductSearch
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index([Bind(Prefix = "Product")]ProductSearch productSearch)
    {
        return Content(productSearch.Title);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <input type="text" name="Product.Title" id="Product_Title" />
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to respond, but it doesn't address the question I've asked. I have a work around for the above problem which is to remove the Product prefix from the inputs, but I'm still interested to know whether the scenario above is obtainable.

Comment: @DrRob, yes, it is obtainable, it's what the first part of my answer addresses.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean I would have to change this line <input type="textbox" name="Product.Title" id="Product_Title"/> to <input type="textbox" name="ProductSearch.Title" id="ProductSearch_Title"/> which is exactly what I don't want to do

Comment: @DrRob, no, you have to change the name of your action argument to `product` instead of `productSearch`: `public ActionResult Search(ProductSearch product)`

Comment: Sorry I think you need to read the question again - can you bind <input type="textbox" name="Product.Title" id="Product_Title"/> to public ActionResult Search(ProductSearch productSearch)??

Comment: @DrRob, I have just tested with `public ActionResult Index([Bind(Prefix = "Product")]ProductSearch productSearch)` and it worked fine. Inside the controller action `productSearch.Title` was correctly bound. Could you provide an example with your model, controller and view allowing to reproduce your problem?